# Does Swirl have a bug, or is my RStudio glitching?

Tags: r, swirl

I am currently making my way through Swirl, and I seem to be stuck on this part. As you can see, it doesn't accept (what I think is) the right answer, and when I try to skip it just takes me out of Swirl. Not sure what the problem is here, should I just uninstall and reinstall?

```
| Use dir.create() to create a directory in the current working directory called
| "testdir".

> "testdir"
[1] "testdir"

| Not quite! Try again. Or, type info() for more options.

| Type dir.create("testdir") to create a directory in the current working
| directory called "testdir".

> dir.create("testdir")
Error in dir.create("testdir") : unused argument ("testdir")
> dir.create(testdir)
Error in dir.create(testdir) : unused argument (testdir)
> dir.create("test.dir")
Error in dir.create("test.dir") : unused argument ("test.dir")
> skip()
Error in dir.create("testdir") : unused argument ("testdir")

| Leaving swirl now. Type swirl() to resume.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing I can imagine is that you accidentally created your own function called `dir.create` that takes no arguments:

```
dir.create <- function() {}
dir.create("testdir")
## Error in dir.create("testdir") : unused argument ("testdir")
```

Try

- `find("dir.create")` (the answer *should* be "package:base")
- `base::dir.create("testdir")` (should work)
- `rm(dir.create)` (should remove the bogus function)
- `rm(list=ls())` to remove all objects from your workspace (note that this [does not completely reset your R session](https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2017/12/workflow-vs-script/) ...)

or, restart a **clean** R session (make sure you don't have a `.RData` file with the bogus function stored in it).  Uninstalling and reinstalling is overkill unless something truly weird is happening.

Comment: Well, `base::dir.create("testdir")` didn't work, but when I tried                     
`dir.create("testdir")
Warning message:
In dir.create("testdir") : 'testdir' already exists

| Nice work!` That did work! So, I think you were right, I probably made my own function somehow, and now that I've started a clean R session (I think? Does closing out of RStudio and then reopening it count?) it worked. Thanks!

Comment: closing and reopening RStudio *usually* works to reset, unless you have saved a workspace as `.RData` (which can happen without your really meaning to)

Answer (score 0):

To the second part of your question: why `skip()` skips to the main menu and not just skips the question: Yes there does seem to be a glitch.

I had a similar issue (using Rstudio, and swirl) three are different definitions for `skip()`:

Rstudio cursor highlight on `skip()`: 'return to main menu'
`?skip()`: 'Skip the current unit of instruction.'
`info()` menu: 'allows you to skip the current question'.

I am a novice so I don't know if its that the swirl `info()` menu definition of 'a learning unit' is incorrect or Rstudios is.

Again, just for the `skip()` question issue: I found a solution here from @Daniel Miller its for the the question in the logic section causing the glitch for me (below) so that I could continue the lesson. But you would need to tailor your own work around by finding and deleting the glitch question for the lesson you are in by editing the lesson .yaml file, which as the answer below shows can be found here (swapping out "Logic" for whichever lesson is causing the problem): `file.path(find.package("swirl"),"Courses","R_Programming","Logic","lesson.yaml")`
.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/76974153/22640198